# Trying to find out what's wrong with our external hard drive?

Tags: external-hard-drive, port

[image: picture of external hard drive]

We have had the external hard drive since 2010 and we've had ongoing issues with it for the past 2 years. I'm hoping I can find out exactly what's wrong with it.

Details: 
BUFFALO 500GB Hard Drive

The issues: 
There is possibly a problem with the port as we've tried several wires but we have to put the external at awkward angles, squeeze it into tight spaces and bend the wire cable if necessary in order for the device to show up. One slight movement and the device disappears, whether it's connected to our Playstation 3 or our laptop.
The blue light is erratic and back when we purchased it the light meant it was working and functioning. Now even when the light flashes albeit rarely the device doesn't show up.
The humming in the external is on and off.

Is there a way I can fix it or extract the data safely? Is there a way to repair the port?

Comment: Crack open the case, remove the HDD, and plug it into a compatible enclosure.  That might work.  This particular brand is nortoriius for its bad quality

Comment: There is some nice wood under all that paint!

Answer (score 3):

It definitely sounds like the USB port is damaged.  I wouldnt bother with repairing it, as you can buy external drive bays fairly [cheaply](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B011I5ZTIS).  You should be able to open up the case and remove the hard drive.  You can than connect the drive to another PC, using another USB drive case, a SATA to USB [adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HJZJI84), or internally on a SATA connection.

Comment: FYI another reason not to repair it is that newer USB drive bays or adapters will be faster, as you can get USB v3.  If your old drive bay was USB v1 or even v2, the speed difference will be like night and day.